# Is there any Python-like interactive console for Java?

Tags: java, console

I spent a lot of time programming in Java recently, and one thing I miss from scripting languages was the ability to test them  in a console.

To quickly test a java program, I have to edit a file, then turn it to bytecode and execute it. Even using an IDE, it loses its fun after the 372 th time.

I would like to know if there is a product out there that features anything like an interactive console (I bet you need a JIT compiler) and some autocompletion (with relexivity, I suppose it's possible).

Maybe that's something very common that I just don't know about or something completely impossible, but its worst asking :-)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes; [jshell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8), and before that some close approximations are [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), [Clojure](http://clojure.org/), [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), and the [Bean Shell](http://www.beanshell.org/).

Comment: Agreed.  I use BeanShell through [JDE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/) in emacs; it's far from perfect, but it provides an interactive console, and decent completion support, both in the console and while editing your regular Java files.

Comment: Indeed, it's very primitive but much better than nothing. Thank to you, and thanks to the guys who coded it :-)

Comment: Also Scala with Eclipse IDE plugin, has interactive console for REPL style execution. See http://www.scala-ide.org/

Comment: @JulianSquires: is there a step-by-step anywhere?

Comment: I haven't used that BeanShell setup in many years.  I would start from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JavaDevelopmentEnvironment if I were trying to set it up again.

Comment: It's amazing how much things change in 9 years.

Answer (score 13):

Funnily enough, you get an interactive console with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/Project/) ! You don't get *much* more Python-like.

Comment: a bit synthetic, but this is the answer I prefer!

Answer (score 12):

Java REPL
http://www.javarepl.com/term.html

with an intellij plugin:
http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7215?pr=

Answer (score 10):

JShell is now standard in Java 9.
[JShell introduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm)

Comment: This is way better answer now (since November) than it looks from the votes, maybe it even should be accepted @e-satis.

Comment: how do i invoke jshell?

Answer (score 9):

Try [Dr Java's](http://drjava.org) "Interaction Pane".

Comment: Yeah I really miss it. now I change to Eclipse but I don't know how to get an Interaction Pane in Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

An approach that I have used to some degree of success is to debug in Eclipse and use the display view. What the display view gives you is the ability to manipulate the code currently running in the JVM through executing Java statements. Any object available at the particular break point you are stopped at is in scope within the display view. While this isn't exactly what you are looking for it does provide some of the features that a REPL provides for other programming environments. See [Debugging with the Eclipse Platform](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/) for more information.

Comment: I still prefer Scala IDE Eclipse plugin, however when it's not desirable to install a plugin, the Debug approach is the closest you can have to a REPL interpreter, that's built-in "feature" in Eclipse JDT. :)

Comment: How to display the value of an expression from th display view? For instance, if I write something like: 

  String s = "Hello World", s1 = s.substring ( 3, 5 );

how to know the value of s1? I cannot find a way

Comment: You can highlight `s1` then bring up the context menu. There is an entry on there labeled `Display` that will do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can execute Scala interactive interpreter too.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) to run arbitrary Java code.  If you want Eclipse integration,  [EclipseShell](http://eclipse-shell.sourceforge.net/) has BeanShell support.

Answer (score 1):

Jgrasp IDE have a interactive console where you can test in,
i use it a lot, and there is alos a debug view showing variabel etc
efter you have deklare them.

It is opensoruce and you can get a copy att
http://www.jgrasp.org/

// Anders

Comment: I looked around JGrasp, but couldn't find an interactive console

Answer (score 0):

I've occasionally run into the same problem and have a partial solution.  I keep around a file (as Charlie Martin said, Java needs its class contexts) that is little more than a test program.  In a second window - a console - I have a script that I run that just checks the modification time of the source file every second or two.  When it sees the source change, it re-compiles it (I'm usually fiddling in C, but I've done this with Java, as well) and executes the result.

It's not a great solution, but its a fast one-off and I've found it to be very useful.