# does netbeans have something like Eclipse Debug display view

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, netbeans

does netbeans have something like Eclipse Debug display view?

I love the interactive window for trying out Java code in Eclipse debug mode, and it's mentioned in this post:

[Is there any Python-like interactive console for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787313/is-there-any-python-like-interactive-console-for-java)

Just wondering if I can get the same in netbeans

Comment: did you ask `Uncle Google` ?

Comment: While in be if mode, open up the watches window. Y add a new watch which will allow to basically type in the value you want to evaluate, including any active variables

Comment: ogzd, I always ask uncle google first :-) I ask on SO because I can't find an answer on Google or in the docs. MadProgrammer, thanks yes, I saw that, but I guess I can't type method calls in there ...

Answer (score 26):

There is a menu option: Debug - Evaluate Expression...

And also a shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (in Windows)

You can see an explanation at [How to Evaluate Code](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/run_debug_japps.htm#sthref409)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an interactive window for debugging quite like Eclipse, although you can set up breakpoints in the program while debugging to follow the step by step route in which the program executes. Have you looked at the NetBeans site? http://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html

Comment: good to know thanks - yes, I've been debugging in netbeans and that's all well and good, but I'd love to be able to play with code then the debugger is paused, and do more than just inspect variables.  I guess I'm spoiled by being able to do that in Eclipse, and in the basic ruby debugger and in Chrome console after having set a JavaScript breakpoint ...

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, press ctrl+shift+I to evaluate an expression. In the "Evaluate Expression" window you can do the same as in eclipse's display window.

Comment: In Netbeans 8.2 (I can't speak to other versions) the mapping is `Ctrl+F9` and is found under the "Debug" menu.